# How to add product name in parent category in magento 2

Tags: magento2, category-products, submenu

i have one parent category like name is :- "test". So i want to show product name in test sub-category.Like this structure.

```
Test - main category
  - Tops - product name
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible if the user comes from the category page to the product description page but if he/she comes from a search or direct URL then their thing is going to be interesting (Only if the product is selected by multiple categories). Let see what answer you get

Comment: You want to show the customer traverse history or you want to show from which category that product belongs?